# How to use "Devnagri (Marathi) Letters" in snappy PDF?

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, snappy, laravel-snappy

I am using Laravel Snappy to generate pdf.
But on PDF Devnagri Words not coming, Instead of such words random symbols comes.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is your font working in HTML?

Comment: Yes. It is working in HTML for normal view.
Just not getting printed on PDF.

Comment: how you have loaded the font?

Comment: <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
    </head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            top: 35px;
        }
</style>